# converting string to float in python

Tags: jupyter-notebook, python-3.7, valueerror

I am using Jupyter notebook to extract data from a csv file.

```
import csv
f=open("temp.csv","r", encoding="cp949")
data=csv.reader(f)
header=next(data)
max_temp=-999
max_date=" "
for row in data:
    if row[-1]==" ":
        row[-1]=-999
    row[-1]=float(row[-1])
    if max_temp<row[-1]:
        max_temp=row[-1]
        max_date=row[0]
f.close()
print("Maximum temp of seoul is ", max_temp, "and the date is ", max_date)
```

[the csv file that is used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ST0LC.png)

The error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-cebb81fe8d99> in <module>
      8     if row[-1]==" ":
      9         row[-1]=-999
---> 10     row[-1]=float(row[-1])
     11     if max_temp<row[-1]:
     12         maxtemp=row[-1]

ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

comes out. This error only comes out for certain computer. Why is this? How can I resolve this?

Comment: Can you print row[-1] before and post here output?

Comment: row[-1] may contain newline character at the end. Either try `row[-1]=float(row[-1].strip())` or print row[-1] as Wonka suggested.

Comment: What is the value of `row[-1]`? even if its a string(ex :` "-999"`) it should just work fine

Comment: The issue is due to space characters. There could be more than one space in the `row[-1]` value. So better solution will be to get rid of spaces and then check for empty string.

Answer (score 0):

pandas more helpful

```py
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv('temp.csv',names=['col1', 'col2','col3', 'col4'])
print(df)
print(df['col1'][0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your for loop as below:

```
for row in data:
    if row[-1].strip() == '':
        row[-1] = -999
    row[-1] = float(row[-1])
    if max_temp<row[-1]:
        max_temp = row[-1]
        max_date = row[0]
```